# CS50:Credit. Why is "4062901840" not getting evaluated as INVALID, if every other 10 digit number is indeed evaluated as INVALID?

Tags: if-statement, cs50

After resolving the **CS50 credit** problem set, my only problem is that card number **4062901840**, does not pass the test. Running check50 says that after enter this number, **it should print "Invalid"** (which is correct, is a 10 digit number) but **instead prints " "**.

Already ran 20 tests using 10 digit numbers and all 20 passed the test correctly, the code is pretty simple since i tried to use only what we´ve been taught so far and don´t use arrays or other libraries. Can you point me in the right direction to know why this is happening?

The program should ask for a number, and evaluates if it meets the luhn algorithm, which is:

- Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s
  second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.
- Add the sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
- If the total’s last digit is 0 (or, put more formally, if the total
  modulo 10 is congruent to 0), the number is valid!
- After that, the program should check if the card number is amex, visa, mastercard or invalid

The conditions for every card type are:

-American Express (15 digits)
Start with 34 or 37

-Mastercard (16 digits)
Start with 51, 52, 53, 53 OR 55

Visa(13 or 16 digits)
Startt with 4

Here is my code

#include <cs50.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

```
long cnum, cnumClone;

int count, first, tempo, sum = 0;

do{
    printf("Enter card number\n");
    scanf("%ld", &cnum);
} while(cnum == 0);

// Clones card number to manipulate it through the iteration
cnumClone = cnum;
//Count every digit of the entered card number
for(count = 1; cnumClone != 0; count++)
{
    //Get the last digit
    tempo = cnumClone % 10;
    //Remove last digit
    cnumClone /= 10;
    //Select digits to be multiplied
    if(count % 2 == 0)
    {
        tempo *= 2;
        //In case the product is a 2 digit number
        if (tempo >=10)
        {
            tempo = tempo % 10;
            tempo += 1;
            sum += tempo;
        }else{
            //Add to the sum
            sum += tempo;
        }
    }else{
        //Add to the sum directly if it wasn´t a every other digit
        sum += tempo;
    }
}
//Last step of Luhn´s algorithm
if (sum % 10 == 0)
{
    //Since count initiates on 1 for iteration purposes, take away 1
    count -= 1;
    // If card number length is 16 checks if it´s a mastercard or visa
    if(count == 16)
    {
        first = cnum / 100000000000000;
        if(first == 51 || first== 52 || first == 53 || first == 54 || first == 55)
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }else{
            first = first /10;
            if(first == 4)
            {
                printf("VISA\n");
            }else{
                printf("INVALID\n");
            }
        }
    }
    // If card number length is 15 checks if it´s an amex
    if(count == 15)
    {
        first = cnum / 10000000000000;
        if(first == 34 || first == 37)
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }else{
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
    }
    // If card number length is 15 checks if it´s a visa
    if (count == 13)
    {
        first = cnum / 1000000000000;
        if(first == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
    }
}else{
    //If card number has a length different than 13, 15 or 16
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

}

Thanks in advance, hope i use this forum the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
}else{
    //If card number has a length different than 13, 15 or 16
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

What does the first `}` in the phrase close? Hint: it has nothing to do with the length. Suggest the length tests be if...else if...else if...else; the (new) final else outputs the INVALID message.

Answer (score 0):

Before this line

```
}else{
    //If card number has a length different than 13, 15 or 16
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Consider adding another else block, that takes care of less than 13, it works for me: like so

```
if (count < 13)
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Hope that helps